# 2G,3G,bitrate shifting in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to have bitrate shifting between 2G and 3G.
i have found connectivity_Action method in  connectivity manager to know if the connection is changed.
Please let me know if this event will be called whenever there is a change or do we have to set any timer for the check.

Please let me know its ussage and any other better way to do this bitrate shifting.

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation for the [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

> Class that answers queries about the
>   state of network connectivity. It also
>   notifies applications when network
>   connectivity changes. (...)
>
> The primary responsibilities of this
>   class are to:
>
> 1. Monitor network connections (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.)
> 2. Send broadcast intents when network connectivity changes
>      (...)

From point 2, you can see that it sends out broadcast intents whenever the connectivity changes. This means that if you want to be notified by this, you must create a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and set it up to listen for the correct intent (i.e. [`CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) in your case).